# Should implement a session includes and objects creation in every controller in ZF2?

Tags: session, authentication, ldap, zend-framework2

I have implemented LDAP authentication in my application, and I want to store username into session and have to check all the Controller/Action should be run if the LDAP user is logged in.

For this, should I use this following Container in every Module Controller and should I write a following constructor in every Module/controller in ZF2?

```
 use Zend\Session\Container;


public function __construct()
{
   $this->session = new Container('user');
    // Check the user is already logged in
    $sesUserNameExists = $this->session->offsetExists('username');
    $sesUserName = $this->session->offsetGet('username');
}
```

Is there any simple way to manage session in all the Modules/Controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you have repeatable logic in different controllers, think of a controller plugin to implement the logic DRY. You can use this plugin in every controller you need the check:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!$this->ldapAuth()->isLoggedIn()) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The controller plugin must implement the interface `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\PluginInterface`, but it's easier to use the provided abstract `AbstractPlugin`:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\Session\Container;

class LdapAuth extends AbstractPlugin
{
    const SESSION_KEY = 'user';

    protected $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->session = new Container(self::SESSION_KEY);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return isset($this->session->username);
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->session->username;
    }
}
```

The only trick in this setup is that you need to register the plugin in the service manager. So take your `module.config.php` configuration file and add these lines:

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'ldapAuth' => 'MyModule\Controller\Plugin\LdapAuth',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the DISPATCH event in onBootstrap() method of your module. There, using the Service Locator you should create an instance of your LDAP/session component and verify that user is logged in. If not, you can short circuit the application flow and redirect user to the login page.